# Different ways to orient the spin in the same direction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics

I know that all electrons have quantised spin. But how can one orient all the spins of a given bunch of an electrons in the same direction?

I know one way is that we pass the electrons through a uniform magnetic field (which is I guess from where the 'magnetic quantum number' name of the spin comes from). But *why* does this method does so? And is there any other way one can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (uniform) magnetic field by itself does not orient spins in the same direction. What really happens is that in the magnetic field the spins of different orientations have different energy:
$$E_\pm = \pm \frac{\hbar\omega_g}{2}
$$
The spins undergo equilibration towards thermodynamic equilibrium - e.g., via amitting photons of frequency $\omega_g$, accompanied by a spin-flip. So we end up with spins having probability to be in a certain state:
$$
P_\pm = e^{\mp \frac{\hbar\omega_g}{2k_B T}}
$$
Thus one ends up in most of the spins oriented in one direction.

Another widespread method to polarize spins is by using a strongly inhomogeneous magnetic field, where differently polarized spins are pulled in different directions. Details of thsi method are usually described in connection to [the Stern-Gerlach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment) experiment (the simples treatment is presented in the Feynmann lectures), but this method is also important for creating population inversion in the ammonia maser (the first quantum generator) and Hydrogen masers (the current frequency standard).

Comment: Interesting this is QFT right? can the emitted photons be observed by any chance?

Comment: In the general sense, photon emission is a subject of QFT, but you don't necessarily need to invoke it here. One could simply talk about spontaneous emission or even about *equilibration* in thermodynamic sense, without specifying the mechanism.

Comment: okay thanks! and is there any conclusive evidence that these emitted photons to be observed?

Comment: Yes, they are real (i.e., not virtual) photons. Somewhat similar setup is used in electron spin resonance (ESR) and nuclear magnetic resonance (NMR, known also as MRI).

Comment: @Vadim Thanks very much for the detailed answer. Could you please answer my second question also (i.e. Is there any other way one can achieve uniformity in the spin)?

Comment: @AgrimArsh I have added a description of one alternative method, but I could not claim knowledge of all the possible alternatives.

Comment: @Vadim Yep got it, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Spin (a purely quantum phenomena) was discovered to explain very fine splitting in Emission spectrum which was very much similar to the splitting that happened in presence of a weak magnetic field.

Yes you are right. So spin accounts for a very small magnetic moment in particles (including electrons), the magnitude depends on the particulars about the particle and so interacts with magnetic field.

Hence to orient spin in free particles, we simply place them in a uniform magnetic field and the magnetic moment will align along the direction of the magnetic field just like a bar magnet would do.

[Magnetic Quantum Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_quantum_number) has very little to do with spin as such, its a set of numbers that assign certain magnetic properties to [orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) that come out as solutions to the so called Schrodinger Equation.

Answer (score 0):

Spin was introduced to explain the hyperfine splitting in the emission spectrum of atoms under the influence of a magnetic field. This was done because the deflection of charged particles under the influence of a magnetic field (Lorentz force) and because the gyroscope effect (with its deflection transverse to the rotation and the applied force) were known phenomena. Since electrons were considered exclusively as electric charges, a rapid rotation of the electrons (considered to be point-like) was explained as the cause of an electric current leading to a magnetic field.

> But how can one orient all the spins of a given bunch of an electrons in the same direction?

For free electrons simply the external magnetic field align the electrons magnetic dipoles all in the same direction. For bounded in atoms electrons the possible alignment depends from the strength of the bounding between all the electrons and the nucleus.

Comment: @HolgerFielder Thanks very much for the answer, but I couldn't understand that how their can be a rotation of the electron, considering it's point, as you have written? Also, if I am not wrong, the actual 'spinning' picture of the electron has been quite abandoned. So what exactly do you mean by 'a rapid rotation of the electron'?

Comment: Agrim That is exactly the point. How is a point-like structure supposed to rotate? The concept has been discarded, but the view that this gives the electron a magnetic field has persisted.